# Interpolate (x,y) values to their corresponding RGB values

Tags: javascript, colors

Ok, so say I have a a 400x400 square. the corner (0,0) is red, the corner (400,0) is green, and (400,400) is blue and the colors spread out from their corner (the last corner is white).

So given a random point, how does one interpolate the RGB values? So if we are looking at the point (350, 180) and RGB values can range from 0 to 1. I am not getting how to interpolate this into RGB values. Something with dot product I guess but I can't figure out how the dot product needs to be used. Whenever I attempt to find something online everyone suggests HSV or whatever, which won't help me as I need the RGB.

Once I figure out a formula I will be putting this into javascript code.

I would LOVE some help on this as I have been hung up on it for quite some time.

Comment: Calculate the distance to each corner and mix them according to that ratio!

Comment: Lol that is what I don't get. What exactly do I do with the distance from the point to each corner?

Comment: LERP! See [Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). In this case [Bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) might be more apt.

Comment: Lol I saw those too... What would be the function? How do I multiply by some f(x1,y1). What would be the answer considering I am after (r, g, b).

Comment: Oh wait, so keeping the 4 corners the same and knowing their colors, to find the red component of my point, I plug the 4 corner coordinates into that equation of the bilinear interpolation page, and f() is just the number of the red component at whatever point?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve exactly? Just guessing, it sounds to me like you are trying to do a colour selector of some sort. If that is the case, your approach will not represent the full rgb colour space.

Nowhere in your square you would have the RGB value of Magenta = full red + no green + full blue = rgb(255,0,255).

To be able to represent all rgb colours and saturations you would need a colour wheel like https://color.adobe.com

Or you would need to manipulate the Hue in your square to travel through the colours. This is probably why you find people suggesting going HSL/HSV, like done here https://www.colorcodehex.com/html-color-picker.html

The math presented here might be helpful in accomplishing your goals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB

Comment: @Reeno, thanks for the update. Starting out with no rep, makes StackExchange fairly difficult to navigate (max 2 links, no ability to comment).